# UITableView Section Header Behavior iOS 9.X vs 10.x

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, sectionheader

I am having an issue where my tableView:viewForHeaderSection: is being called a different amount of times in IOS 9.X VS 10.X.

In 9 it only gets called once(which is incorrect) while in 10 it gets called for all the correct sections I have set in the FRC.

Is anyone aware of any difference in how an FRC handles the sectionNamekeyPath between 9 and 10?  I haven't successfully found anything in the documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: Because I need all the section headers, so when it is called only once i am only getting 1 section header in 9...  When there should be multiple sections in my tableview.  10 works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

here below solution Working for me both iOS9 and iOS10

The use of **tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:** requires that you also implement **tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:**. This should return an appropriate non-zero height for the header. Also make sure you do not also implement the **tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:**. You should only use one or the other (viewForHeader or titleForHeader)

Comment: Ankur, That is the implementation I have.  So, unfortunately that doesn't help.